# Override syntax highlighting settings

Tags: vim

I have the following in a vim plugin, and I have also moved it to the end of my `.vimrc`:

```
syn keyword javaScriptIdentifier const
```

However, this doesn't work and `const` is not highlighted properly in JavaScript files. If I run `:syn keyword javaScriptIdentifier const` after opening a file, *then* it will be highlighted properly.

I am using pathogen with quite a few plugins, but I would think these all run before then end of my `.vimrc`. Some of them are using an `after` directory, but I don't see `const` anywhere in those plugins. I also don't see it in the system JavaScript syntax highlighting.

Is there any way to ensure that syntax highlighting or other operations take priority?

Comment: which plugin are you talking about? why do you want to move the line to your vimrc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting `syn` in your `vimrc` will never work, since existing syntax rules are cleared when changing the syntax highlighting. Consider:

```
:set syntax=javascript

" Oops, this is a Python file, change the syntax
:set syntax=python
```

What would happen if existing syntax rules *wouldn't* get cleared?

You'll need to use the `after` directory, which you already seem to be familiar with, or use an autocommand:

```
autocmd Filetype javascript syn keyword javaScriptIdentifier const
```

You can view an autocommand as roughly similar to events in JavaScript, in the sense that they run a piece of code whenever the user does some action.

> I am using pathogen with quite a few plugins, but I would think these all run before then end of my .vimrc

That depends on the plugin. You can hook into autocommands like above, and in addition to that many plugins use the `autoload` feature (meaning a file won't get loaded until it's needed).